# Google Maps Static Map - Fit Map Width to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, google-maps

The Google Maps Static API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) hard codes the height and width of the map as a URL parameter in pixels. Is there any way to have the map render 100% width and 100% height of the parent container?

Comment: You need to calculate the dynamic size required in pixels for the request.

Comment: @Paul how does gmap supposed to know whether 100% amounts to 700px or 1200px? and since it's static it cannot re-render itself. You need to handle the resize as well as initial loading dimensions

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI use GeometryReader to get the width of the parent container and pass it to the google static map url.